# In excel differentiate delimiters from content characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, reader

I have an excel .csv file which looks like this

```
id,ticker1,ticker2,Company,Supplier
9,MMM,DHR,3M Company,Danaher Corporation
10,MMM,IBM,3M Company,International Business Machines Corporation
11,MMM,UNP,3M Company,Union Pacific Corporation
12,MMM,TMO,3M Company,Thermo Fisher Scientific Inc.
13,MMM,NSC,3M Company,Norfolk Southern Corporation
61,No,0,,
14,MMM,TER,3M Company,"Teradyne, Inc."
```

The data here is comma seperated so I use  `delimiter=','`, but in some cases as in last line there is comma in text too. In my csv file all strings with comma in it are in quotation mark `" "`. I have tried to read the file with open()

> **with open('file.csv','r') as f:** 
>      for row in f.read().split('\n'):

But this way I have to handle commas and empty values. So I am curious which is the correct way of working with damaged csv files? should I use  regex expressions or libs like pandas ?

Comment: Use pythons built in csv module and it will handle this for you

Comment: @ChrisDoyle how can I make it differentiate the comma in quotation mark like this "Teradyne, Inc." and comma used as delimiter ?

Comment: It handles it all for you. Its a very well written module and well tested. Let me post an answer as an example.

Comment: I have tried with csv lib yes it's a written lib, but in my case it was removing 'Teradyne' from "Teradyne, Inc."

Comment: have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use pythons `csv` module. its designed for exactly this purpose. To take away the complexity of things like parsing csv data where the deliminator can appear inside fields etc.

here is a simple example. I use the `csv` modules `DictReader` this will read the first line of the CSV as key names then map each subsequent row as key values. it automatically takes care of the comma inside the supplier field.

```py
import csv

with open("sample.csv") as my_csv:
    for row in csv.DictReader(my_csv):
        print(f'id {row["id"]} has supplier "{row["Supplier"]}"')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
id 9 has supplier "Danaher Corporation"
id 10 has supplier "International Business Machines Corporation"
id 11 has supplier "Union Pacific Corporation"
id 12 has supplier "Thermo Fisher Scientific Inc."
id 13 has supplier "Norfolk Southern Corporation"
id 61 has supplier ""
id 14 has supplier "Teradyne, Inc."
```

Comment: so quotation mark is to differentiate the delimiter from string character ?

Comment: In a CSV file, the general rule is if you have the deliminator char in your field value, then you should quote that field so that csv parsers know not to split that field as the deliminator is inside quotes so is part of the field value and not a field seperator.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

```
with open('file.csv','r') as f:
content = f.read()
content = content.split('\n') #split paragraph
data = []
for i in content:
    data.append(i.split(',')) #split each value
```

The expect result will be a list of list. All data missing will be denoted as "", in which you could change to other denotation during the loop in "content".

Comment: how you handle commas in content ? Like this one "Teradyne, Inc." in the last line ?

Answer (score 0):

In my specific case all commas in text where before `"Teradyne, Inc."`so I removed  comma using replace function `string.replace(', Inc','')`. After I removed the commas in text I could `split(',')` each row/line as described in answer [Long Doan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65538120/6687545) below